# tasksel: apt-get failed (100)

Tags: linux, debian, gui, xfce

I was installing `Xfec` desktop environment in the Debian 8 OS. I logged in as `root` and command `tasksel` in the shell. Among the other chooses, I selected the `Xfce`

[image]

At the time the installation is few seconds left, I get the message `tasksel: apt-get failed (100)`.

[image]

I did an `sudo apt-get update` but the issue seems stayed as it is after the next try. What to do now?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to check logs in `/var/log` to see _why_ apt-get failed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1.Check your `/etc/resolv.conf`.

> This means checking your DNS settings for visiting website correctly. You can Google Public DNS address on internet :)

2.Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

> This means checking your "Ubuntu Update Servers" list for using "apt-update" command.

3.Run `apt-get update && apt-get install vim`(or whatever the app is) for testing to see if it works.

4.Reboot and try it again...

> Thanks for guys who given any suggestions :)

Comment: This answer isn't very useful to inexperienced Linux users... a little more background on *what* to "check" would be helpful.

Comment: @Dave After over half a year of using Linux, I agree that the answer requires to be comprehensive.

Comment: Since, this is the accepted answer and no answer seems to have the combination of explanation and remedies, I want to add a comment to request explanation as well. For me, `apt-get update` worked, not `dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: this worked for me, but i also agree that skipping straight to the third option just coz of not knowing what to look for isn't ideal for an answer

Answer (score 16):

This just happened to me. In my case the problem was caused by an previously interrupted package transaction. The solution was to run:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

After that, `tasksel` worked as expected.

(short quick answer, just in case it helps someone out!)

Comment: As an addendum, if you get an error about missing dependencies you might need to run a `apt install -f` afterwards.

Comment: This saved me after accidentally killing tasksel in the middle of installing and removing software. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem and both answers above helped me, I restarted it a couple of times and final time this worked

```
sudo apt-get update 
dpkg --configure -a
```

and finally

```
sudo tasksel
```

Comment: Yup.  It was the apt-get update that fixed it.  Not sure if the dpkg --configure -a was required, but hey, why not?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - the error code given by tasksel (100) is rather non-descriptive; I found out the actual reason why it failed in my case when running the tasksel command from the cli:

```
apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop
```

Gives the following error message:

```
0 upgraded, 904 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 680 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,279 MB of additional disk space will be used.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

After extending the root partition, the command completes without problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge
sudo apt-get update
sudo tasksel
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this error after installing the `gnome-shell` package on raspbian with `apt`, subsequently uninstalling it, then trying to install GNOME again with tasksel.

I solved the problem by running `sudo apt install gnome-software`, which resolved a dependency conflict, and allowed tasksel to continue.

Comment: This worked, thanks.