# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Server)- tasksel: apt-get failed (100) while installing ubuntu-desktop

Tags: installation, ubuntu-20.04, dependencies

**PROBLEM: On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Server), installing ubuntu-desktop through tasksel fails with error "tasksel: apt-get failed (100)".**

**SOLUTION 1: Restore last good checkpoint.**
The simplest solution is to roll back your system to your last good checkpoint and install tasksel then ubuntu-desktop cleanly. If that is not an option for you, see the next solution.

**SOLUTION 2: Check that you have tasksel dependencies installed using the commands:**

- sudo apt list --installed debhelper*
- sudo apt list --installed dpkg-dev*
- sudo apt list --installed gettext*
- sudo apt list --installed po-debconf*

If you are missing these packages or they are not the correct version, install/upgrade them. In my case, debhelper was not present. The debhelper package cleans up your machine if partial or conflicting files are present. tasksel actually lists it as a dependency, probably for this reason.
Details on tasksel dependencies are [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/tasksel).

---

---

**System Details:**
My server is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (focal) on amd64 architecture on a VM in Hyper-V. The Ubuntu OS is up to date.

**Steps to Produce Error:**

- I installed tasksel using *sudo apt install tasksel*.
- I called tasksel using *sudo tasksel*.
- I highlighted the package "ubuntu desktop" and pressed Enter.
- Install failed with the error:
- **tasksel: apt-get failed (100)**

**Remedies Attempted:**

- I checked that /etc/apt/sources.list enabled my focal repos (they are enabled).
- I tried several combinations of *sudo apt update*, *sudo dpkg --configure -a*, and restarting the server. [Sources here](https://superuser.com/questions/1280568/tasksel-apt-get-failed-100).
- After all this, using *sudo tasksel* and attempting Ubuntu-desktop installation failed with the same error.
- **tasksel: apt-get failed (100)**

I checked the [Ubuntu tasksel Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/tasksel) and saw that tasksel has 4 dependencies as follows:

1. debhelper (>= 9)
2. dpkg-dev (>= 1.9.0)
3. gettext
4. po-debconf

**Remedy That Worked:**

- I checked my Ubuntu installation using *sudo apt list --installed debhelper* and saw that I do not have debhelper installed. The other 3 dependencies were installed and the correct minimum versions.
- I installed debhelper using *sudo apt install debhelper*.
- I reran *sudo tasksel* and selected ubuntu-desktop.
- This time, tasksel ran without error.

Comment: I want to point out I have attempted to recreate this error on a reverted VM, but I cannot! 
I don't know how I bungled the tasksel installation to fail into "apt-get failed (100)"

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck apt-get error following the steps you used to reproduce error. But then I was looking at the guide for install KDE GUI and directly used this command:
`sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop`

and it was able to install what's needed. I'm using ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS as well.